# Make category to increase Navigation bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change height of my navigation bar, and i did that with following:

```
CGFloat navBarHeight = 100.0f;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, navBarHeight);
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
```

I want to add this functionality to `UInavigationBar` category. However, i don't know how to do that. How to add that block of code to category of `UInavigationBar`?

Comment: You would be changing a fundamental part of iOS that users have been learning for the past 8-9 years. I'd think very hard about changing something like that unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Fogmeister that is why i want to use category instead of subclassing. Also, users may differ in their needs :)

Comment: that reply is not relevant to what I wrote. :-/

Comment: @Fogmeister what if i need to change its height? Is that forbidden to do that..

Comment: I didn't say it was forbidden. Nor did I say you shouldn't do it. But iOS is a system and all the apps live within that system. Its users expect it to work in certain ways and look certain ways. They have learned that over a long period of time. You are now wanting to change that. I said that you should only do it if it's absolutely necessary and I cannot think of a reason why it would be. Maybe it is absolutely necessary but you run the risk of putting off users by changing it unnecessarily.

Comment: @Fogmeister well, the reason of do that is that - app creating for single person, not App Store. That is why i dig into it, not really wanted to though.

Comment: ah, in that case then it's no problem changing it at all :-)

Answer (score -2):

Add below line

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```